# Invariant Violation: expected symlink targets to be populated

Tags: react-native, expo

Invariant Violation: expected symlink targets to be populated at invariant (C:\Users\bujda\OneDrive\Dokumenty\rect\reactnative\ShoppingList\node_modules\invariant\invariant.js:40:15)
at TreeFS.bulkAddOrModify (C:\Users\bujda\OneDrive\Dokumenty\rect\reactnative\ShoppingList\node_modules\metro-file-map\src\lib\TreeFS.js:257:32)
at HasteMap._applyFileDelta (C:\Users\bujda\OneDrive\Dokumenty\rect\reactnative\ShoppingList\node_modules\metro-file-map\src\index.js:691:16)
at async C:\Users\bujda\OneDrive\Dokumenty\rect\reactnative\ShoppingList\node_modules\metro-file-map\src\index.js:327:9
at async DependencyGraph.ready (C:\Users\bujda\OneDrive\Dokumenty\rect\reactnative\ShoppingList\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:95:5)
at async Bundler.ready (C:\Users\bujda\OneDrive\Dokumenty\rect\reactnative\ShoppingList\node_modules\metro\src\Bundler.js:69:5)
at async IncrementalBundler.ready (C:\Users\bujda\OneDrive\Dokumenty\rect\reactnative\ShoppingList\node_modules\metro\src\IncrementalBundler.js:289:5)
at async Server.ready (C:\Users\bujda\OneDrive\Dokumenty\rect\reactnative\ShoppingList\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1085:5) {
framesToPop: 1
}

this error occures when i start my expo project by command npx expo start I dont know what to do

I have searched the internet but i couldnt find anything